# How to fix a bundler error when upgrading Ruby from version 2.7.5 to version 3.0.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler

I was updating the Ruby version on my rails application. I updated from version `2.7.5` to version `3.0.6`. I fixed all the broken dependencies and my project is successfully launched using the `rails s` command. But for some reason I can’t run rspec tests.

In my `config/application.rb` file the following line is throwing an error.

```rb
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

The error is like this:

```
ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)
# ./config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:4:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

What's strange is that this error only reproduces when there is a `:test` or `'test'` in the `Rails.groups` array.
That is, if, for example, you give the `Bundler.require` such an array as input -> `[:default]` then there will be no error

version of my rails app: `6.1.7.4`

Comment: please add your application.rb to the question. The error is on line 16.

Comment: what groups do you have in your Gemfile? did you by any chance add any group which isn't `:production, :development, :test`?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found the answer. The problem was in the capybara library. For some reason, the version I was using was not marked as unavailable for Ruby 3, updating to a more recent one worked as it should.